# uitableView, new view with tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableView I have tabs too:

[image]

When I click a cell, it opens a new viewControler, but I cant set the tabs, how can i do this?

Thank you in advace!

Comment: You should clarify exactly what's happening that's wrong, and explain more clearly what you want to happen instead, and if you share code it will help greatly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using this code...
when you are selecting cell

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```